# Observar um elemento quando surge uma nova classe

Tags: jquery

Seria essas barras fixas de frontend, o problema é que eu não encontro como é inserido uma classe para por coisas nela.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="main-menu">conteudo</div>
```

Após rolar um pouco a tela é inserido a classe:

```
<div class="main-menu isStuck">conteudo</div>
```

E preciso ficar observando quando coloca e quando remove essa classe para por uns "clones" dentro dela.

Comment: Após rolar a tela, a div ganha a classe, ok! E quando ela irá perder a classe, quando rolar pra cima?

Comment: @DvD Isso após rolar novamente ate o estado inicial ela some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `.on` com `scroll` para observar, ao rolar a tela, se o elemento tem ou não a `class`:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
   if($('.main-menu').hasClass('isStuck')){
     console.log("tem a classe");
   }else{
     console.log("não tem a classe");
   }
});
```

Comment: Isso ja ocorre, e eu não posso sobrescrever o evento, eu preciso detectar quando a class "isStuck" surge e some da div

Comment: @Dexxtz Não entendi direito. Pode tentar explicar melhor?

Comment: @Dexxtz Bom, se entendi, a div ganha a classe sem estar relacionado à rolagem ao topo da tela, é isso? A rolagem pode ser em qualquer lugar da tela?

Comment: Funciona assim, ja existe um evento que coloca e remove a classe apartir da rolagem da tela, eu preciso de um observador nessa div, e saber o momento que a classe é inserida e removida, exemplo em algum momento da rolagem essa div vai ganhar uma classe que minha condição vai inserir conteudo, mas eu não sei em qual momento isso vai ocorrer, eu não posso refazer esse evento de rolagem a penas detectar tipo bind, trigger essas coisas

Comment: @Dexxtz Atualizei a resposta. Veja se era isso.

Comment: @Dexxtz Se vc já tem um observador "scroll", não há problemas em adicionar este ao código, ele vai trabalhar em paralelo ao outro, de forma separada.